# TextView in Android XML is not showing all of my text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, textview

A have a constraint layout with some images and texviews. My textview has the top, bottom and start constraint in the imageview.
But the issue is texviews do not display all the text.

I can't change the groupview and need to keeping use the constraint layout.

[design with the images and texviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSiJU.png)
[text is not full display in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGPuZ.png)

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".instructions.InstructionsFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shoeListIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_shoe_list"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextsStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            android:text="In this App you can see your list of shoes with it type and image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/shoeListIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/shoeListIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/shoeListIcon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addNewShoeIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_add"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/shoeListIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shoeListIcon" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextsStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            android:text="You can click on the add button to add a new pair of shoes."
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/addNewShoeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/addNewShoeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/addNewShoeIcon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shoeLDetailIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_shoe"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/addNewShoeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addNewShoeIcon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teste"
            style="@style/TextsStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            android:text="You can click on an image to see the shoe's details as name, size, description, etc"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/shoeLDetailIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/shoeLDetailIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/shoeLDetailIcon" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried another stackoverflow answers. I used TexView atributties as MaxLines, SingleLine = false, constraintbies = 0. But nothing solved my problem.

Comment: What is the amount of `@dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size`?

Comment: add here some picture

Comment: Did you try constraining with end_toEndOf="parent" and setting width of textView to 0dp?

Comment: @dimen/dimen_instructions_image_size is 100dp

Comment: @Yurii I added two pictures they are above in a link text ---design with the images and texviews text is not full display in the emulator

Answer (score 3):

You can see what's happening in your design view:

[image: The design view example image posted in the question]

Your `TextView`s extend off the edge of the screen, because they're not constrained to that edge, and their width is set to `wrap_content`, i.e. *"as wide as the text they contain"*. Because your text doesn't fit on the screen, the end of the `TextView` ends up pushed out of view.

You need to do things the other way around - the `TextView` needs to be set/constrained to a suitable size, so the text contents fit to *that*. That means either setting a fixed `layout_width`, or using constraints like `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` to lock the *end* edge to the side of the screen (with `layout_width="0dp"` to allow the `TextView` to size to fit that constraint).

That way, the width is limited, and the text needs to flow to the next line if it's too long. You can keep `layout_height` as `wrap_content` to allow it to grow as that wrapping happens - obviously if there are too many line wraps, it'll grow too tall, and then you'll have to worry about things like the `maxLines` and `ellipsize` attributes, adding a `maxHeight`, or otherwise restricting the height. If both dimensions are restricted, then that puts a limit on how much text you can display!

It's also possible to keep the `TextView` with a `wrap_content` width, and place it inside a `ScrollView` which *is* constrained to a certain size on the screen - that would allow you to drag the text to see more of it (basically sliding the view from side to side so you can see different parts of it through the "window" the `ScrollView` creates) but that really depends on what you want.

---

From your layout, I'm guessing you just want a fixed label next to each image. So I'd:

- constrain the end of the `TextView` to the end of the `parent` (you'll want some padding/margin in there somewhere too)
- constrain the top and bottom of the `TextView` to the top and bottom of the `ImageView` (so it's vertically centred)
- maybe rewrite your labels so they're not as long (some writing guidance [here](https://m2.material.io/design/communication/writing.html#principles))

You also need to test how it looks with various screen sizes, at various system font sizes (if the user has set their phone to use large text, anything that uses *sp* dimensions will be larger and take up more room). If your labels are long, and the `TextView` could end up taller than the `ImageView`, you might have to start using [`Barrier`s](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-to-a-barrier) so things can be constrained to the appropriate elements depending on which is largest. (Which is another good reason to keep your labels concise if you can!) There are lots of ways to define these limits about how your space is used, it's up to you how you want to do it.

Comment: Awesome explanation! I used constraint End_toEndOf="parent" and layout_width="0dp" and this solved my problema. But I learned much more with your anwser. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I rendered your view in android studio,
your views are going out of the screen
just add this line to all your text views to prevent them from going further than the parent or screen

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```